# How to use color and symbol at the same time?

Tags: symbols, color, write

How can I write in LaTeX, for example: `\sanela{}` but in red color? I typed `\verb|\sanela|\{\}` but it seems like a lot to type? How to add color red here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could you be your choice by using the `xcolor` package to get the colored text:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
{\color{red}\textbackslash \texttt{sanela}\{\}}
\end{document}
```

to get

[image: Moreover, it doesn't matter whether]

you are using symbol or not, when you use colors just create your closed environment by enclosing whatever you need in the desired colors within `{\color{yourcolor}.....your data.....that can also span multiple lines....or even equations......}`

[All the immediately available colors are listed in this link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors)

Comment: `\color{red}\textbackslash \texttt{sanela}\{\}` is more similar to `\verb|\sanela|\{\}`

Comment: @CarLaTeX I didn't know that before, I shall play with that as well. Also, updated my answer by including the `\texttt{.}`

Answer (score 7):

To me it looks like two questions. The first is how to write `\sanela{}`, and then the basic `\verb|\sanela{}|` is probably the simplest form. The second is how to get it colored, and then things get more complicated. `\verb` is a bit special as command and it connat be used as argument to other commands. One idea is to use `tcolorbox` where you can define your own (inline) verbatim command. If you have non-white background you might want to change `colframe` and `colback`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myTestVerb}{O{black}v}{%
  verbatim,
  top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
  boxsep=0pt,
  leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,
  colframe=white,colback=white,
}{\color{#1}#2}
%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
Text \myTestVerb{\sanela{}} \myTestVerb[red]{\sanela{}} Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvote your answer (+1). It is very nice. I have undestood thath the user want to write `\sanela{}` not in verbatim.

Comment: @Sebastiano, Yes you might be rigth that is not about colored verbatim, even though `\verb` is mentioned. The question is not entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `newverbs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs,xcolor}

\newverbcommand{\redverb}{\leavevmode\begingroup\color{red}}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

Normal \verb|\sanela{}| and red \redverb|\sanela{}|

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more customizable version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newverbs,xcolor}

\newverbcommand{\colorverbgeneric}{}{\endgroup}
\newcommand{\colorverb}[1][red]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
  \color{#1}%
  \colorverbgeneric
}

\begin{document}

Normal \verb|\sanela{}| and red \colorverb|\sanela{}|
and also green \colorverb[green]|\sanela{}|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash sanela\{\}}
\end{document}
```